# Effective parallelization of the inner loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp, pragma

I have this sequential code:

```
for (unsigned item = 0; item < totalItems; ++item) { // Outer loop
// Outer body
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j) { // Inner loop
  // Inner body
  }
}
```

My goal is to simply parallelize the inner loop. It could be done like this:

```
for (unsigned item = 0; item < totalItems; ++item) { // Outer loop
// Outer body
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j) { // Inner loop
  // Inner body
  }
}
```

The problem of this code is that on every run of the outer loop new threads are spawned. In order to speed up this code, I want to create a team of threads in advance and used them multiple times. I found that for this purpose there is a directive `#pragma omp for`.

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (unsigned item = 0; item < totalItems; ++item) { // Outer loop
// Outer body
  #pragma omp for
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j) { // Inner loop
  // Inner body
  }
}
```

However, if I understand it correctly the usage of the directive `#pragma omp parallel` leads to the fact that outer loop is run multiple time. Is this correct?

**Edit**:
Here a more detailed example:

```
// Let say that the image is represented as an array of pixels
// where pixels is just one integer.
std::vector<Image> images = getImages();

for (auto & image : images) { // Loop over all images
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < image.size(); ++j) { // Loop over each pixel
    image.at(j) += addMagicConstant(j);      
  }
}
```

**Goal**: I want to spawn a team of threads and then used them repeatedly to parallelize only the inner loop (= loop over the image pixels).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [omp parallel vs. omp parallel for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448318/omp-parallel-vs-omp-parallel-for)

Comment: see https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/ "The parallel construct starts a parallel block. It creates a team of N threads" thus threads remains there during the whole parallel section; they are "used" in the for loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does OpenMP handle nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13357065/608639) and [Nested loops, inner loop parallelization, reusing threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27342408/608639). If I am parsing things correctly, only the outer loop needs OpenMP attribute of `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)`.

Comment: This is really over thinking and under estimating the OpenMP powerful features. by default OMP will make the thread pool no need to worry about that.

Comment: We cannot answer this without knowing anything about * "inner body"* and *"outer body"*. Please prepare a [mcve] or at the very least clearly describe what is done in those regions

Comment: what do you mean by "to parallelize only the inner loop"?  Be more specific. What is parallelizing inner loop and how is it different from parallelizing outer loop.

Comment: After you've edited your question my response is even more clearly the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly valid and will indeed work:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (unsigned item = 0; item < totalItems; ++item) { // Outer loop
// Outer body
  #pragma omp for
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j) { // Inner loop
  // Inner body
  }
}
```

`#pragma omp parallel` will spawn the threads. Each thread will then proceed through the outer loop. At each loop iteration, the threads will hit the `#pragma omp for` and the inner loop will be distributed among the threads. There is an implicit barrier at the end of each `omp for` block, so threads will wait until the inner loop has been completed before moving to the next outer loop iteration.

Having an `omp for` distributed loop within another for or while loop, or within a conditional section is possible if it is guaranteed that all threads will go into the loop.

It is forbidden however to use constructs such as :

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (unsigned ii= 0; ii< omp_thread_num(); ++ii) { // Number of iteration of outer loop depends on the thread
// Outer body
  #pragma omp for
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j) { // Inner loop
  // Inner body
  }
}
```

or

```
#pragma omp parallel
if(condition_depending_on_thread_num) { 
  #pragma omp for
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j) { // Loop
  // Inner body
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned item = 0; item < totalItems; ++item) { // Outer loop
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j) { // Inner loop
  }
}
```

Comment: This will parallelize also the outer loop and that wasn't what I really want to.

Comment: That is exactly what you want. You want each thread to work on a single item. That way you will avoid cache miss orgy and get the maximum performance.